# woocommerce by default first variation price add in to cart always

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a variation in woo commerce product. Currently my product have 3 variations with different prices. So I want that On the shop page when I select variation and click on add to cart button always add first variation price on cart not selected variation price.

Comment: Do all of your variations have the attributes set to the different dropdowns? If not, it will automatically choose the first variation in the list because the first variation 'matches'.

Comment: thanks for your replay but i get solution